# FILTRAR UN SELECT DINAMICO CON LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, select

Hola estoy practicando en laravel y tengo un formulario donde el usuario completa sus datos, en los cuales esta su colonia, codigo postal, pais, estado y ciudad, pero tengo un problema al cargar los datos puesto que tengo en mi base de datos de colonias 146,759 registros de todas las colonias de mexico y se traba para cargar tantos datos, estuve leyendo en internet que existe una forma de cargar los datos del select mediante otro select dinamicamente y por medio de javascript, pero sincermente soy malisimo para el javascript, **espero alguien pudiera orientarme para reducir la carga de datos**.

se me ocurre que al seleccionar el estado, se filtre los datos del select solo a las colonias de ese estado, la estructura de mi tabla "colonias" es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualmente tengo en mi formulario wizard.blade.php asi:

```
   <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">{{ __('forms.Colonia') }}</label>
<div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
<select class="form-control kt-select2" id="kt_select2_1" name="param">
 @foreach($colonias as $colonia)
<option value="{{$colonia->id}}">{{$colonia->nombrecolonia}}</option>
@endforeach
 </select>
</div>
</div>
```

configurada mi ruta de la siguiente forma:

```
Route::get('/wizard', 'DeniedController@index', ['as' => 'denied', function() {
            return redirect('home')->with('status', 'No tienes permiso de ingresar a esta ruta porque ya configuraste tu empresa');
            }])->name('wizard')->middleware('denied');
```

El controlador DeniedController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use App\Colonia;
use App\Empresa;

class DeniedController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
     public function index()
    {
        $colonias = Colonia::all();
        return view('admin.wizard', compact('colonias'));
    }
}
```

y el modelo colonias:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Colonia extends Model
{
     /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'colonias';

    /**
    * The database primary key value.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
}
```

Comment: De quien depende colonias?

Comment: Como de quien depende? no entiendp, si se trata de que filtraria las colonias, seria al seleccionar estados

Comment: Primero tendrías que normalizar tu base de datos. El campo `estado` debería ser un ID y los estados estar en su propia tabla. Lo mismo con `tipoasentamiento`, `municipio`, `ciudad` y `zona`. Una vez hecho eso primero armarías el select de `estados` y una vez seleccionado un estado harías la consulta a tu base de datos para traer las colonias correspondientes. Normaliza la DB, actualiza tu pregunta y te ayudamos con el resto.

Comment: Segui tu consejo y lo hice @azeós pero me tope con otro problema, espero puedas ayudarme, la pregunta nueva que abri es https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283734/error-de-filtro-en-select-dinamicos