# Error de Filtro en Select Dinamicos

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, html-select

El problema es que filtre los datos de mi base de datos porque son 145,958, mediante `selects` dinámicos, que al momento de que el usuario seleccione el país, le muestre los estados de ese país y a su vez las ciudades de ese estado y por último solo las colonias de esa ciudad.

Alimente mi base de datos y cree las relaciones entre tablas sin problema y al seleccionar el país si me muestra los estados relacionados.

El problema es que al seleccionar el estado, en ciudad esta no carga absolutamente nada.

No se que estoy haciendo mal simplemente deja todo en blanco, siento que algo no anda bien en mi archivo `JS`, no soy muy bueno en `javascript` haha.

Espero puedan ayudarme a ver que anda mal:

Adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo mi código de la siguiente manera ¿Que estoy omitiendo o haciendo mal?

Primero cree el modelo `Country`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
        protected $table = 'Countries';
        protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

El modelo `Town`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Town extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'towns';
    protected $fillable = ['name','state_id'];
    public static function towns($id){
        return Town::where('state_id','=',$id)
        ->get();
    }
}
```

Y el modelo `State`:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class State extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'states';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'country_id'];
    public static function states($id){
        return State::where('country_id','=',$id)
        ->get();
    }
}
```

Después cree la rutas y las dirigí a su función correspondiente en el controlador `DeniedController`:

```
Route::get('states/{id}', 'DeniedController@getStates');
Route::get('towns/{id}', 'DeniedController@getTowns');
```

El `DeniedController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use App\Country;
use App\State;
use App\Town;

class DeniedController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
     public function index()
    {
        $countries = Country::pluck('name', 'id');
        return view('admin.wizard',compact('countries'));
    }
    public function getStates(Request $request, $id){
        if($request->ajax()){
            $states = State::states($id);
            return response()->json($states);
        }
    }
    public function getTowns(Request $request, $id){
        if($request->ajax()){
            $towns = Town::towns($id);
            return response()->json($towns);
        }
    }
}
```

Cree el archivo `JS` que se encarga de recibir los id y filtrar llamado dropdown.js y lo incluí en la vista:

```
$("#country").change(function(event){
    $.get("states/"+event.target.value+"",function(response,country){
        $("#state").empty();
        for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
            $("#state").append("<option value'"+response[i].id+"'> "+response[i].name+"</option>");
        }
    });
});

$("#state").change(function(event){
    $.get("towns/"+event.target.value+"",function(response,state){
        $("#town").empty();
        for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
            $("#town").append("<option value'"+response[i].id+"'> "+response[i].name+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Y por ultimo en el formulario agregue los `select`:

```
 {!! Form::select('country',$countries,null,['id'=>'country', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!} //Se encarga de listar los paises
{!! Form::select('state',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],null,['id'=>'state', 'class'=>'form-control']) !!}//Lista los estados que corresponden al pais
{!! Form::select('town',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],null,['id'=>'town', 'class'=>'form-control']) !!}//Lista las ciudades del estado seleccionado
```

Las migraciones están de la siguiente manera:

Migración de `Countries`:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
             $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Migración de `States`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('states', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id');
        $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Migración de `Towns`:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('towns', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('state_id');
            $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('states')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Y migración de `Colonies`:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('colonies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('town_id');
            $table->foreign('town_id')->references('id')->on('towns')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hay que probar donde se está generando la falla. Primero hacé un `console.log('event')` dentro del `$('#state').change()`, antes del `$.get()` para ver si ese bloque de JS se está ejecutando. Si se está ejecutando, hacé un `console.log(response)` dentro del `$.get()` para ver que está devolviendo PHP. Más allá de eso, las relaciones entre las clases no las tenes hechas de la mejor manera. Leé la documentación de [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). Publicá el código de las migraciones o tu estructura de la DB para ver si está bien hecha.

Comment: Listo, agregue el codigo de las migraciones y tambien realice las modificaciones que me sugieres, note que al hacer el console.log('event') no obtiene bloqueo ni error, pero cuando hago el console.log(response) todo esta en blanco

Comment: Dejá el `console.log(response)` y dentro del `getTowns()` hacé primero un `dd($id)` para ver si está llegando el ID. Después hacé un `dd($towns)` (antes del return), para ver que está obtenido. Igual vas a tener que armar las relaciones entre las clases de manera correcta, pero eso después lo vemos.

Comment: Al hacer cualquiera de los dos dd($id) o dd($towns) me imprime como 100 veces "undefined" en la variable, puedes verlo en este link https://ibb.co/3c3zSFr, eso significa que no esta recibiendo los parametros correctamente ni el id, como solucionaria esto?

Comment: Fijate con las herramientas de desarrollador, en la solapa de red, que te aparece en respuesta al hacer un `dd()` de esas variables. Lo que estás mostrando no sirve porque es lo que imprime JS, lo que quiero ver es que genera PHP.

Comment: Ok, realice los pasos que me indicas https://ibb.co/tcc8ZHM y note que en el caso de los estados ejecuta "1" o "2" que son los id de los paises y los envia a la url http://aplicacion.test/states/2, pero cuando selecciono el select de estados envia el nombre del estado y no la id atraves de la url asi: http://aplicacion.test/towns/Sinaloa te adjunte los screen en esta url https://ibb.co/tcc8ZHM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que no estas generando correctamente el `HTML` para que el `option` tenga un `value`, ya que te esta faltando agregar el `=` entre el atributo `value` y el valor `'"+response[i].id+"'`.

Esto provoca que el `option` no tenga un "`value`", lo que resulta en que el valor del mismo sea igual al texto que contiene.

#### [`HTML <option> -> Atributo value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/option#Atributos)

> El contenido de este atributo representa el valor que será enviado al enviar el formulario si una determinada opción está seleccionada. Si se omite el atributo el valor  se tomará del texto del contenido del elemento option.

### Solución:

```
"<option value='"+response[i].id+"'> "+response[i].name+"</option>"
```

#### Ejemplo:

```
$("#state").append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'> "+response[i].name+"</option>");
```

Comment: No lo puedo creer jaja tienes toda la razon, ese fue el problema que soluciono todo, muchas gracias!