# poner datos en un select de acuerdo a la opción de otro select usando laravel o javascript

Tags: javascript

básicamente tengo un `<select>` para países y quiero en el otro `<select>` me aparezcan las ciudades que estan relacionadas mediante llave foranea `country_id` al código del país que he seleccionado. Por ejemplo si el código del país que he seleccionado es `COL` que me traiga de la BD la ciudades cuyo `country_id` sea `COL`?

No se si se pueda hacer directamente con laravel o ¿hay que usar JS?

select países:

```
 <select class="p-1 pl-3 form-control" id="country_id" name="country_id">

   <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione un pais</option>

   @foreach (\App\Country::all() as $country)

     <option value="{{ $country->code}}">{{ $country->name}}</option>

   @endforeach

 </select>
```

select ciudades

```
<select class="form-control" id="city_id" name="city_id">

  <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccionar una ciudad</option>

  @foreach(\App\City::where('country_id',old('country_id'))->get() as $city)

    <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{$city->name}}</option>

  @endforeach

</select>
```

informacion adicional = los paises y ciudades estan almacenados cada uno en su respectiva tabla en un BD

Comment: Depende, quieres o no quieres se recargue la página?

Comment: @BetaM que no se recargue

Comment: Entonces ocupas AJAX, para que una vez que ocurra el change en el primer select, tomes el id de ese valor elegido, hagas la consulta a ciudades y llenes el segundo select (*idea al aire*), la pregunta es muy amplia y casi quue basada en opiniones, busca y trata algo, busca como *selects dependientes*

Comment: [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283734/error-de-filtro-en-select-dinamicos) podría serte útil.

Comment: si no quieres complicarte puedes usar fetch consumiendo otro recurso de tu aplicacion, manejas el evento por js y cuando se seleccione un pais envia a back end el id y que te retorne las ciudades, no es buena idea anidad un select

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas forzosamente utilizar JavaScript, le agregas un evento **change** para que detecte cuando hayas seleccionado algo, capturas el ID, mandas una peticion al servidor con ese ID y en el servidor se me ocurre que hagas un **INNER-JOIN** para obtener las ciudades que correspondan al pais que seleccionó el usuario.